# Angular 5: Property 'description' does not exist on type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, angular5

During `ng build --prod`, I see the error coming:

> ERROR in src/app/book/book.component.html(49,12): : Property
>   'description' does not exist on type 'any[]'.

My **book.component.html** is follows:

```
<p>{{books_edit_data.description}}</p>
```

My **book.component.ts** is as follows:

```
export class BookComponent implements OnInit {
books_edit_data = [];

constructor(private bookService: BookService) {
  }
editBook(id){
  this.bookService.getBook(id).subscribe(data => {
      this.books_edit_data = data;
      //console.log(this.books_edit_data);
  });
}
```

and my **book.service.ts** is as below:

```
getBook(number): Observable<any>{
    const url = `${this.url}/api/book/`+number+`/edit`;
    return this.http.get(url,{headers: new HttpHeaders({Authorization:'Bearer '+ this.token})});
}

console.log(this.books_edit_data);
```

> {id: 1, author: "Mr. Jorge Fahey IV", description: "Lizard, Bill, was
>   in such long ringlets, and mine …ase your Majesty?' he asked. 'Begin
>   at the March.", created_at: "2018-03-22 02:26:45", updated_at:
>   "2018-03-22 02:26:45"}

Any suggestion on this?

Comment: why dont you create strong class

Comment: What does `console.log(this.books_edit_data);` print?

Comment: Is it possible that `books_edit_data` has multiple books and a singel book has the property `description`? For example: `books_edit_data[0].description`

Comment: @MikeBovenlander - ts getBook(number): Observable<any> ..means return single only , is it correct ?

Comment: try to use `{{books_edit_data?.description}}`

Comment: @bugs - {id: 1, author: "Mr. Jorge Fahey IV", description: "Lizard, Bill, was in such long ringlets, and mine …ase your Majesty?' he asked. 'Begin at the March.", created_at: "2018-03-22 02:26:45", updated_at: "2018-03-22 02:26:45"}

Comment: @MikeBovenlander when I console.log the variable, it returns {id: 1, author: "Mr. Jorge Fahey IV", description: "Lizard, Bill, was in such long ringlets, and mine …ase your Majesty?' he asked. 'Begin at the March.", created_at: "2018-03-22 02:26:45", updated_at: "2018-03-22 02:26:45"}

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: added my answer might help you, by looking at your code you dont need array , you need single element declartion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its should be like

```
books_edit_data:any; and html will be 
<p>{{books_edit_data?.description}}</p>
//if you want to intialize it then 
books_edit_data:any = {};
```

as you are returning single element only from your method `getBook(number):`

with this declaration `books_edit_data = [];` it becomes array and array in javascript dont have `description` property, based on code i see that you are passing id and expecting only one element out of your server call.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the array element with object's property. you should use ngFor or use index to access the specific element

```
<p>{{books_edit_data[0].description}}</p>
```

if you are strong that it return one element, change it as

```
books_edit_data :any = {};
```

Comment: its getBook(number): Observable<any> ..means return single only , is it correct ?

Comment: @PranayRana look at his declaration

Comment: then its error with declaration ...as per the code it retuns only one

Answer (score 1):

declaring it as followed will avoid the error but isn't pretty. It is better to create a class for the data.

```
<p>{{books_edit_data['description']}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of dealing with asnyc call you must use safe navigation operator like this

```
{{books_edit_data?.description}}
```

also code for declaration should be like this(as pranay suggested) -

```
books_edit_data:any;
```